# How to spy/stub/mock firestore db.collection().add() when db is a custom class property, i.e. how to stub this.db.collection().add()?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, mocha.js, sinon

I have a class, Firestore, that inits a firebase db in the constructor, this.db, and has an addEntry() method that adds a new entry to the db. How can I stub/mock the write to the db so that no writes are made during testing? The assertion of this test is that db.collection().add() is called once.

firestore.js

```
    class Firestore {
    
        constructor() {
            this.db = firestoreAdmin.firestore()
        }
    
        async addEntry(newEntry) {
            newEntry.claimed = "false"
            var collectionReference = await this.db.collection('collection_name').add(newEntry)
            
            return collectionReference._path.segments[1]
        }
}
```

test_firestore.js

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
const chai = require('chai')

const Firestore = require('../firestore.js')


describe('file firestore.js | class Firestore', function() {
    const firestore = new Firestore()

    describe('method addEntry(newEntry)', function() {
        it('should call this.db.collection().add() once', function() {
            var newEntry = {
                "client": "clientName"
            }

            var add = sinon.spy(firestore.db.collection, 'add')
            firestore.addEntry(newEntry)
            sinon.assert.calledOnce(add)
            add.restore()
        })
    })
})
```

Right now I'm getting this error:

```
  1 failing

  1) file firestore.js | class Firestore
       method addEntry(newEntry)
         should add key:value pair (claimed: false) prior to writing to db:
     TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property add as function
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `spy` [sinon doc](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.2/spies/), consider use `stub` [sinon doc](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.2/stubs/). A `spy` will wrap the original function and does exactly what the original function does, in your case, write to the database.

Meanwhile, a `stub` should be used when you want to prevent a specific method from being called directly.

```
var add = sinon.stub(firestore.db.collection, 'add')
```

With the comments below, it looks like you are trying to stub a complex object, in this case, you can actually assign a new value to the property without any sinon methods like this:

```
    const fakeAdd = sinon.fake()
    firestore.db.collection = [
      {add: fakeAdd}
    ]
    
    firestore.addEntry();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(fakeAdd)
```

And for async method unit testing, you can simply mark the test method as `async` as well.

```
it('should do something', async () => {
  await firestore.addEntry()
})
```

A working codepen example:
https://codepen.io/atwayne/pen/VweOXpQ

Comment: Thank you @lastr2d2. I made the change but a new error arises. I see your codepen example and I think I understand, but I think the main trouble arises from the firebase dependency. Making your suggested change yields `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property add`.  `var add = sinon.stub(firestore.db, 'collection')` actually runs and yields a warning, `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`. I'm wondering if the root issue is related to the async nature of the parent function.

Comment: then stub on `collection` and return an array, and create a `fake` object and insert as the first element of the array

Comment: Thanks again lastr2d2! Along with your changes I made the `firestore.addEntry();` call async, since the firestore `collection.add()` funciton is async. I forced resolved the promise for the test case and it seems to be working correctly. I'll be looking it over today to make sure.